# PHPmailer using smtp doesn't work at cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, phpmailer, cpanel

phpmailer work when I use localhost, but not working when I move it on Cpanel.
PHPMailer folder located at third_party and PHPMailer.php & PHPMailer_load.php file located at libraries.
I use codeigniter 3

```
function sendEmail($email, $reset_key, $db){
  global $error;

  $this->load->library('PHPMailer_load'); //Load Library PHPMailer

  $mail = $this->phpmailer_load->load();

  $mail->isSMTP();  

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 

  $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

  $mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';

  $mail->Password = 'pass';

  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

  $mail->Port = 587;

  $mail->setFrom('noreply.com', 'Admin'); 

  $mail->addAddress($email,'Admin');

  $mail->Subject = $subject;

  $mail->msgHtml($message);

  if (!$mail->send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

  } 
  }
```

I get Error

```
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: Have you checked that SMPT is enabled at Server? Have you found any error?

Comment: Please [search before you post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+cpanel)

Comment: @Synchro I've done, but not work for me

Comment: So what happened when you tried the tests described in the troubleshooting guide the error message points you at? It is very, very likely that your hosting provider blocks outbound SMTP, so it probably has nothing to do with your code.